# Add script that moves the object of the game from side to side

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am struggling a little bit to add a script that moves the object of the game from side to side.

I want to create a function to move the object of the game from left to right and to avoid collision of other objects.

```
public AudioManager2 audiomanager;
public GameManager gamemanager;



private float xposition;
public GameObject character;
public Sprite[] characters;
public bool teleporting=false;
private int n;
void Start(){
    ZPlayerPrefs.Initialize("group123", "happyapplications2016");
    teleporting = false;
    n = ZPlayerPrefs.GetInt ("CHARACTER");
    Debug.Log (n.ToString ());
    character.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = characters [n];
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    //On circle touching the car, it will play scoreUp audio & send message to gamecontroller to add score .
if(other.gameObject.tag == "Point"){
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
        audiomanager.PlayPoint ();
        ScoreManager.Score++;
}
    //On cube touching the car, it will send message to gamecontroller to end the game.
if(other.gameObject.tag == "Obstacle"){
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        audiomanager.PlayGameOver ();

        ScoreManager.lives--;
        this.gameObject.SetActive (false);
}
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Gear"){
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        audiomanager.PlayPoint ();
        ScoreManager.gearsno++;

    }
    //If touches the floor, reposition it to top
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Floor"){

        this.gameObject.transform.position=new Vector3(this.transform.position.x,5.3f,0);
    }
    //Teleportation to left
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "BridgeLeft") {
        teleporting = true;
        xposition = this.GetComponent<Transform> ().position.x;
        float newpos = xposition - 2.1f;
        this.GetComponent<Transform> ().transform.DOMoveX (newpos, 1.6f);
        if (this.gameObject.tag == "Car1")
            GameController.Car1CurrentPosition = GameController.Car1CurrentPosition - 3;
        else if(this.gameObject.tag=="Car2")
            GameController.Car2CurrentPosition = GameController.Car2CurrentPosition - 3;
        StartCoroutine (ChangeTeleportation (1.6f));
```

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail in what way you're struggling? As in, what your script is doing right now, and how it fails to do what you're trying to achieve? Information like this helps immensely in tracking down the problems in a script.

Answer (score 0):

Create an if statement that allows you too transform the position of the object
 if(other.gameObject.tag == "Floor"){

Comment: How do you return the teleportation state to true. thanks for the previuos feedback.

Comment: Create a public function name it anything you want and return the function like (return = )